how do tube filament resistors work on this Type 10?



picture source: "Building a 1929 style TNT Transmitter", The VE7SL Radio Notebook, 2009 https://qsl.net/ve7sl/tnt.html, originally referenced from the 1929 ARRL Handbook
I don't know how many here are familiar with directly-heated tube technology, but I had a lingering question. This is a schematic for a transmitter from a loooong time ago, and I understand that the "rectifying" resistors, named because they produce a stable-ish DC voltage that uses the midpoint between the two AC peaks in the filament supply (effectively creating a cathode), also reduce the hum on the filaments. What I can't seem to figure out for certain is how these values are computed. The schematic calls for "75 to 100 ohms total", which would mean the values hover somewhere around 32.5-50 ohms. I've figured out two potential ways to calculate them.

I take the AC voltage of either peak, 3.75 volts in this case, and divide it by the cathode bias current. This would make sense from a technical standpoint as far as I can see. The "cathode" would receive the same amperage as the plate, causing the tube to function correctly, and the grid can be driven higher or lower using the oscillator voltage. The resistors could also use smaller wattage values, which is verified by other schematics I saw from around the same time.

I take what I would want to be the grid bias voltage and divide it by the peak filament current per side, so 0.625 amps. This doesn't make as much sense to me because the tube from what I can tell uses a fixed bias, so the only way to get this effect would be to drive it negative, either using the LC network that is connected to the grid, or by applying a negative DC voltage. Plus the power ratings would have to be huge (most type 10s had upwards of a -30 volt potential between the cathode and the grid).


What do you think? I wanted to see if I could get some clarification as to the accuracy of my thought process. I'm new to directly heated tube tech, and I don't have the actual part yet because it's a bit expensive at the moment.

The filament supply is floating, thus is does not contribute to the cathode bias. The cathode is either connected to 0V via C3 and effectively cut-off or connected to 0V via the key and the circuit hopefully oscillates.  R1 is low enough to effectively ground the cathode. R2 effectively sets the grid bias.

Thanks for the reference. I was almost certain it was 80 m. But I see that it can be adapted to nearby bands. I also had figured it was a shunt hartley using copper tubing for L1. That tubing is hot and dangerous to touch, I believe. Normally, L4 goes straight to the plate and C2 would isolate L1 from that voltage. A ground clip near the center of L1 is then used. Safer. R2 is a grid leak, so it's self-biased and grid will be negative with respect to the cathode. Filament is 6 Ohms so R1 sum should be 10 times that, I think. (Rule of 10.) Type 10 says "power audio". Just notes for now.

@periblepsis thank you for all of the insight! In the article the author mentioned it could be adapted for use on 40 or 80m, and proposed the use of a decoupling capacitor to isolate the large coils from the plate voltages. I think I'll be going with that suggestion myself, don't feel like being electrocuted

@Kartman I had a feeling the resistors were essentially used to create a cathode and nothing else, it's necessary with DHTs from what I read. I wanted some idea of how to create this exact resistance value, but I suppose it's simply whatever will provide the filament supply with a path to ground without excessively loading the supply resistance.

@DeWitt2967 I am so excited to hear you are considering this. It was what I cut my young teenage teeth on, circa 1970. Of course, back then, children were allowed to buy explosives and morphine sulfate crystals literally 'over the counter.' (I would go to a local pharmacy at age 15 and they would hand that stuff to me!) So 1000 V plate voltages were nothing to us. (Some of us did die, though. ;) I'm past the time wanting to return to it. Rather buy what I can, build the rest. But back then I had no money and barely enough to eat. (No dad, living in home without walls, etc.) So this was it.

@DeWitt2967 I would recommend expanding your studies a little. I don't know exactly what you want to achieve. But look up George Grammer in 1932 (QST). There is also the 2nd edition of Sterling's "Radio Manual" from 1929, I think. I spent a lot of time studying WW II training manuals, studying WW II 200 mile radar systems (bought one commissioned in 1944), and studying books from the 1950s. For the longest time I had much difficulty "getting the idea" of grid leak self-bias, I admit. Just couldn't quite wrap my teenage brain around it. But finally dawn arrived. Anyway, best wishes! :)

@periblepsis, I really do appreciate all the kind words! I will absolutely be looking into the material you recommended. I am in the process of studying for a radio license, my goal is to get on the air with one of these beautiful transmitters. I found out about the AWA, and I have studied the articles they published a bit. And I'm happy to hear that you are doing better personally when you were younger, We all have issues to overcome, in my case it's been over two years with a chronic illness, but electronics is something that brings me a great amount of joy :)
